# Angular-2 Observable doesn't work

Tags: angular, observable

The following code should log the data from keyup event, taken from an input field, but nothing happens and console stays blank (no errors as well).

```javascript
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup");
        keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using jQuery with angular2 is like having one foot in 2009 and the other in 2016.

Answer (score 5):

You have couple of problems with your code.

1). `Observable.fromEvent` expects HTML element as the first parameter, however you are passing jQuery instance.

2). You are trying to subscribe in constructor which doesn't guarantee that component contents will be loaded by that time.

3). You use hardcoded CSS selector `#search` which you should never do.

Now, this is how you can fix it:

1. Set template reference to input field.
2. Initialize `Observable.fromEvent` in `ngAfterContentInit` hook:

```javascript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input #search type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('search') input: ElementRef

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, "keyup");
    keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5TFDv0OoV8wWnDYneiFD?p=preview

Comment: @ViewChild('search') input: ElementRef;  has red error enlightment. Should I import something on the top?

Comment: Did you check demo? You need to import `ElementRef` from @angular/core.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thank you. But this is not exact output that I wanted. I want to log the whole input value, without a letter separation.

Comment: `keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data.target.value));`?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use **observable** from **Rxjs** when same thing can be achieved with **core angular2**?

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Pipe,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {myservice} from 'app/service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
          <h1>angular2</h1>
            <input #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value,$event)">
    <p>{{values}}</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {       
  values = '';

  onKey(value: string,event) {
    this.values += value + ' | ';
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZSqLNhSi0lI4HdKhulBf?p=preview

official doc : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Comment: It does work, thank you. But I want to log the whole input value, with no letter separation.

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar project when I was using the jquerySelector the  @ViewChild function did not find the element. I changed it for the declarative way: #search and it worked.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:`
    <input #search type="text" class="form-control"  >
`
})
export class AppComponent {

@ViewChild('search') input: ElementRef

ngAfterContentInit() {
    var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, "keyup");
    keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share additional information why your answer is working and what is different from the Question. This would improve it !